# Ionic - Can't generate resources ios

Tags: ios, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, npm

I update the npm with `npm update -g` and now I can't generate ios resources.

For example if I remove android and ios folder and do `ionic cordova resources` just add the android folder.

I also try add with `ionic cordova resources ios` and `ionic cordova resources --icon or --splash` but don't add ios folder.

Add now when I try to generate the ios platform (`ionic cordova add ios@4.4.0`) it returns me and error that I think it's because the resources ios folder are missing.

```
    ✖ Running command - failed!
[ERROR] Exception: Using cordova-fetch for cordova-ios@4.5.1

    Adding ios project...
    Creating Cordova project for the iOS platform:
        Path: platforms/ios
        Package: com.zs.APP
        Name: APP NAME
    iOS project created with cordova-ios@4.5.1
    Error: Source path does not exist: resources/ios/icon/icon-1024.png
```

How can I check ionic cordova ios version?

I don't know what to do, please help me to solve this problem.

Thank you

Comment: what is the icon.png size in your resources folder?

Answer (score 3):

The issue is it needs `icon-1024.png`.

Check the Ionic [blog post](http://blog.ionicframework.com/ios-11-checklist/).

> Xcode needs a 1024×1024 sized icon for submission.

You need to have icon size of 1024x1024 present in the resources path as icon.png
and then run:

```
ionic cordova resources ios --icon
```

Note: you may also need 2732 × 2732 size splash.png to generate splash images for IOS 11.